# Using java to find Happy Numbers: Nested while loop loops indefinitely

Tags: java, while-loop, nested-loops

My assignment asks for a command-line input to be put through nested while loops to find if a number is a happy number or not. So far I have this:

```
int i = 0;
int sum = 0;

int dig2, dig1, dig3, dig4, dig1next, dig2next, dig3next;
int digit1sum, digit2sum, digit3sum;

happyNumber = number;  

while (i < 500){   
    while (happyNumber > 0){       
        while (sum!=1){ 
            dig3 = happyNumber / 100; 
            dig2 = happyNumber % 10; 
            dig1 = happyNumber / 10; 

            dig2next = dig2 % 10;
            dig1next = dig1 % 10;
            dig3next = dig3 % 10;

            digit1sum = dig1next * dig1next; 
            digit2sum = dig2next * dig2next; 
            digit3sum = dig3next * dig3next;

            sum = digit1sum + digit2sum + digit3sum;
            happyNumber = sum;         
        }
        System.out.println("It is a happy number.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    i++;
    System.out.println(i);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

I set i<500 so when i++ reaches 500, the loop should stop. I've pretty much tried putting i++ in every section of the code possible, it never works. what am i doing wrong here?

also: i am not allowed to use for loops or do-while loops on this assignment. i have to use nested while loops only

**Happy number**: Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its digits, and repeat the process until the number equals 1 (where it will stay), or it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1(how long the loop will be: 500).

Comment: I recomend you quickly describe the definition of "a happy number" because at least i wont reverse engineer that on a base which is obviously not producing the correct output ;)

Comment: I also recommend that you format your code more cleanly, and add diagnostics. If your innermost loop *ever* terminates, you're quitting the application - so the outer loops really don't matter.

Comment: what if sum never gets 1? 
I think that is the case..

Comment: Making it a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem would help, too... we don't know the value of `number`.

Comment: Good god they should realy focus on programming in schools rather than make it a fcking mathematical problem (im unfortunately out) too.

Comment: ***Please*** refrain from editing your question to be unintelligible.  Perhaps, others can benefit from your question and gain knowledge too.

Answer (score 2):

After a quick glance at your code:

```
while (sum!=1)
....
sum = digit1sum + digit2sum + digit3sum;
    happyNumber = sum;
```

This while test is likely to be always true -> infinite loop -> stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

You will never get out of your innermost while-loop in case of a number that loops endlessly (it is by no means stopped by the 500- limit and your logic is wrong here).

Secondly, something to think about:

```
    digit1sum = dig1next*dig1next; 
    digit2sum = dig2next*dig2next; 
    digit3sum = dig3next*dig3next;
```

these (digitxsum) will always be positive.

```
    sum = digit1sum + digit2sum + digit3sum;
```

sum will therefore always be positive

```
    happyNumber = sum;
```

happynumber will always be positive

```
    while (happyNumber > 0)
```

what is this for?

Comment: im not sure, it's something my professor wanted in the code. it does seem redundant, i agree.

Comment: what exactly where you told to use? and which parts can you change?